# How to disable weekend dates on calendar mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I am new to **MVC** and **C#.NET** and trying to create a booking system. 
Below is the drop down calendar for selecting the date.

My Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way I can disable weekend dates?

Comment: maybe [this](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/) helps you. look at `eliminate days` paragraph

Answer (score -1):

Are you using jquery datepicker?

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

Comment: No just the calendar from mvc

Comment: The datepicker in MVC is JQuery!